# watch google drive directory for changes longpoll

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a native application that is trying to listen to changes in files of a user's google drive. What I want is something like [dropbox longpoll api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/63/low-latency-notification-of-dropbox-file-changes). I understand that using [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push) of Google drive supports this, but it appears that it requires a domain at which to receive the push notifications. Is it possible to obtain change information on a file/directory without polling, and without setting up a domain?

Comment: The only solution I can see is to write a simple long-poll proxy.

Comment: I would really like to do this without running a server. It seems really stupid that I should have to funnel everyone's personal change data through my server. Is this really what Google wants me to do?

Comment: I can't see an alternative. Google's infrastructure is massively distributed and "owned" by multiple teams, so it would be quite a challenge for them to implement long-poll. Dropbox has the advantage of a more compact infrastructure, all of which is under the control of a single team.

Comment: @pinoyyid that's a bit of an absurd statement.  somewhere, in google, there is something that knows when a document is changed.   that thing, whatever it is, currently publishes events.   having an api subscribe to those events is a fairly simple engineering problem... no matter how big the distributed infrastructure is.   if google hired me to do it, id have it done in about one year.... and it would be well worth it.